# Discussion Board's Last Updated column not being updated

Tags: discussion-board

OOTB behaviour is whenever a reply is added to a thread, the Last Updated column gets updated. However, in one of our discussion boards, the Last Updated column does not get updated and stays on the date & time the thread was started.

Seems that it is only a problem on that particular discussion board because when I created another OOTB discussion board on the same site, the Last Updated column gets updated correctly - it gets updated whenever a reply is added to the thread.

Hope someone could help how to further troubleshoot as it is not an option to recreate the discussion board.

Comment: Im having the same problem. Would you be willing to share your event receiver script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find out the root cause anymore and it's not an option to recreate the discussion board, I eventually wrote an event receiver and attached it to the list. Whenever a new reply is created, the event receiver would update the "Last Updated" column.